# Very suddenly, only purchased music is showing up on iPhone ( but everything is in iTunes)

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

So, yesterday at a stoplight, I was scrolling through the music on my iPhone 5 (running OS 7.1) to play a song (one that I had uploaded to iTunes from my own CD and had recently downloaded to the phone from the cloud).  The light went green, so I stopped fiddling with it until I got to the next light.  At that point, when I looked at my phone, I suddenly didn't see the song I was about to play.  In fact, most of my music wasn't showing up (either on the phone itself or available for download from the cloud).

When I got home, I realized that the common denominator was that all the music showing up as available on my iPhone was music I had purchased via iTunes. None that I had uploaded myself was showing up.

I double-checked the "show all music" setting on the iPhone, and it was still set to do that (as I always have it).  If I turn it off, I don't see *any* music on my iPhone at all.

I've syched and restored my iPhone, but without any results.  All the music is still there in iTunes on my home computer, but only the minority of songs purchased via iTunes is showing up on my phone.

The weirdest thing to me is simply the suddenness of it.  It had been working as it always had, and suddenly wasn't.  It's possible that in my scrolling to find that song, I somehow managed to accidentally switch a setting, but other than that, there doesn't seem to be any obvious cause for the change, unless it's that I haven't updated to the latest OS8 yet.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated!

Peace,

ted

Comment: From your narrative it sounds like you use iTunes Match?  if so, did your annual subscription run out or expire?

Comment: Bingo!  You got it.  I had totally lost track of that.  Once I ponied up the subscription fee again and enabled iTunes Match, everything was hunky dory.  Thanks much!

Comment: I'll move that to an answer, so you can be marked accepted and maybe help someone else.  I made it a comment since you made no direct mention on iTunes Match.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you use iTunes Match? if so, did your annual subscription run out or expire?  if so, you may need to pay the ANNUAL fee and turn the service back on.